# Calculate number of Minimum Spanning Trees

Tags: algorithm, graph

I'd like to know how can I calculate the total number of MST (minimum spanning trees), given a Graph.
**I don't need the code, just the explanation of the procedure**

Comment: @ShashwatKumar If I'm posting here, it means that I've already searched on google

Comment: then hats off to your search skills. I put exactly the title of this questions and good 10s of links where it's fully explained.

Comment: @ShashwatKumar looks like you're one hell of a researcher!

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can have a look at these two papers. If you still need clarification, let me know:

1. [The Number of Spanning Trees in a Graph by Konstantin Pieper](http://wwwmayr.in.tum.de/konferenzen/Jass08/courses/1/pieper/Pieper_Paper.pdf)
2. [Counting Minimum Weight Spanning Trees by Andrei J.Broder](https://doi.org/10.1006/jagm.1996.0851)

You can use Scihub or Sciencedirect membership to access [2](https://doi.org/10.1006/jagm.1996.0851).

You can also test your code by solving this [problem](https://www.spoj.com/problems/MSTS/) on SPOJ.